# Agentless system monitor for multiple Windows machines

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, monitoring, system-monitor

I need an application that, when running on a machine (the *controller*), **can monitor basic system resources and network connectivity** for about 20 Windows servers/clients (the *nodes*), all in the same local network.

**The nodes should be [agentless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agentless_data_collection)**, i.e. no dedicated client/agent should be installed on them.

If necessary, it's acceptable to manually configure any relevant service/permission on a node, as long as it's something that comes with the the OS by default (e.g. PowerShell). Installation of a Java virtual machine is also acceptable.

Supported operating systems for the controller and the nodes:

- Windows 8.1
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows 10

Some other must-have requirements:

- It's free and open-source
- The following data is collected every X seconds:

  - **IP connectivity (ping)**
  - **Uptime/Downtime**
  - **CPU usage**
  - **Physical and virtual memory usage**
  - **Disk usage**
- The controller requires a minimal configuration/setup, possibly without the
  need of prerequisites such as a full-fledged RDBMS or a full-fledged Web Server (e.g. MySQL, Apache).
- The data is saved on the filesystem or on a SQLite database, on the controller.

The nice-to-have requirements:

- The controller can send e-mails to alert predefined users about particular events (e.g. lost of network connectivity)
- The real-time and/or historical data can be displayed remotely on a browser, from a few users on their own machines
- It has ready-to-use plugins to monitor other system resources and/or can be extended by writing custom plugins

Before writing my own, I was wondering if something with these features already exists.

Comment: Do you know SNMP (simple network monitoring protocol)?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose, 10-Strike LANState Pro complies with the most of the required things (visit [link](http://www.10-strike.com/lanstate/)).

```
IP connectivity (ping)
Uptime/Downtime
CPU usage
Physical and virtual memory usage
Disk usage
```

In addition, it discoveries and builds a network map.

However, it is not free and open source.

Comment: open-source is listed as a "must-have".